# Save file after converting from pdf to txt

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have converted some pdf files to read in txt format. However, how do I save it after converting? I was trying to use `file.write('file1')` option, but it seems not to be working.

```
file1 = pdf_to_txt("important_file_1.pdf")
file2 = pdf_to_txt("important_file_2.pdf")
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on how "it seems not to be working"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open a new file with `write` mode:

```
file1 = pdf_to_txt("important_file_1.pdf")
f = open('pdf_to_text.txt', 'w')
f.write(file1)
f.close()
```

To make it reusable do something like this:

```
import time
def save_pdf_to_text(file_to_save, filename=None):
    if not filename:
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
        filename = '{}.txt'.format(timestr)
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(file_to_save)
```

Usage:

```
file1 = pdf_to_txt("important_file_1.pdf")
save_pdf_to_text(file1)
```

it will create a file with timestamp. Or pass filename as second argument.

Comment: Thanks for answering. How would you create a function to repeat the same for many pdfs?